# Dashboard doesn't contain the "Customize dashboard" link

Tags: 7

The dashboard page doesn't contain the *Customize dashboard* link.

[image: screenshot]

A normal dashboard would appear as in the following screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

How do I make the link appear is it should?

Answer (score 1):

To see the *Customize dashboard* link, the logged in user needs the *Admin blocks* permission, as said in admin/people/permissions.

> Customizing the dashboard requires the *Administer blocks* permission.

This is how I see it when logged in as user #1, who has all the permissions.

> [image: screenshot]

This is how I see it with an account without that permission.

> [image: screenshot]

If then I give the *Administer blocks* permission to that account, this is how the dashboard appears.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: this user is Administrator and have the [_Administer blocks_ permission](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WcUxA.jpg).